# Replace string with condition in pandas dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas

I often use this kind of line which create or replace a column and assign a value according to a condition:

```
df.loc[df['somecolumn'].str.endswith('_s'), 'somecolumn'] = '_sp'
```

I would like to do the same thing, but for the index column. My specific question is how do I refer to the index column?

```
df.loc[df.index.str.endswith('_s'), 'index column name?'] = '_sp'
```

I tried using df.index.name, but it creates a new column instead of changing the values within the index column.

Comment: You could add another line:

df = df.set_index('index column name?')

Comment: df.columns return the column names, but I want to call the df.index.name without creating a new column

Comment: Ah... see my updated solution.

Comment: yes of course I could add a new line with set_index, but it will be 2 lines instead of 1...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As i told in the comment section, You don't really need to use `index.str.endswith` until strictly it needs to be rather use anchors like for start `^` and endswith `$` that should do a Job for you.

Just taking @Scott's sample for consideration.

```
df.index.str.replace(r'_s$', '_sp', regex=True)
```

I'm retaining this answer here for the sake of posterity ..

Answer (score 3):

IIUC,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
​
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(5,5)), columns=['a_s','b','c_s','d','e'], index=['A','B_s','C','D_s','E_s'])
​
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_s','_sp')
df.index = df.index.str.replace('_s','_sp')
​
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      a_sp   b  c_sp   d   e
A       51  80    48  93  34
B_sp    96  16    73  15  29
C       27  85    35  93  69
D_sp    92  79    90  71  85
E_sp     4  63     2  77  14
```

Comment: I want to do that with a condition like the one I wrote: if ".str.endswith('_s')"

Comment: There is no need but, you could do something like this: `df.index[df.index.str.endswith('_s')].str.replace('_s','_sp')`

Comment: Even better to use regex method `df.columns.str.replace(r'_s$', '_sp', regex=True)` with  startswith `^` and  for endswith `$`.

Comment: df.index[df.index.str.endswith('_s')].str.replace('_s','_sp') does not work because I need to do df.index = df.index[df.index.str.endswith('_s')].str.replace('_s','_sp') and there is a length mismatch

Comment: for the Scott  +1 as well as i used to follow his tricks as well.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by pygo, this does the trick perfectly:

```
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'_s$', '_sp', regex=True)
```